# How to return JSON from Ajax request function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build a website that uses the client to call an API with JavaScript. I didn't know how to do that so I googled and came across Jquery. Then I wrote my function that makes the request. It looked like the following:

```
async function makeRequest(url) {
  await $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  });
}
```

This works fine and the print statement prints the received data. But if I call this function from another function, it doesn't return anything. It comes out as undefined every time. An example:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function () {
  var players = await makeRequest(
    "https://phijoto.ddns.net/Playtime/playtime.json"
  );
  console.log(players);
});

async function makeRequest(url) {
  await $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  });
}
```

If I run this, it prints out the received data through the second print statement but the first always gives back "undefined". What can I do about that?

Comment: A return in a callback other than a then() often has nowhere to return to. That is definitely true in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **return** something from `makeRequest`.

Also: Don't mix callbacks and promises, at best it makes for confusing code.

```
async function makeRequest(url) {
  const data = await $.getJSON(url);
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}
```